# LG G5 LS992 How can I downgrade from Nougat to Marshmellow?

Tags: downgrade, lg-g5

I tried downloading a ZV4 and ZV5 roms and flash it with LG UP. But the flash always fails with the following error

> Error Code = 0x2BC, Invalid command response code = 0x80000121

Comment: Downgrading across major Android versions is hard or impossible through official means these days, since manufacturers enforce restrictions on bootloaders.